# GRASS GIS line of sight but permeable

Tags: r, gis, grass

## GRASS GIS line of sight but permeable

[image]

### My Data

I have a digital terrain model (brown), a height model for buildings (grey), a height model for trees (green).

### My goal

For light pollution and ecology issues, I'd like to compute light emission on each cell of my digital terrain model from lamp poles.

### My approach

**A lamp pole can be compared to an observer** who will look at each cell of the digital terrain model.

A typical viewshed approach is ok when light traverses buildings because light can't go through it. A binary approach (see/not see) can do the job.

### trees and permeability

But for trees, a typical viewshed approach is not ok. There is an absorbance factor, which can be a function of the number of tree cells that are traversed by the beam of light.

Is there a GRASS GIS function, like `r.los`, that drawes a line from an observer to each cell of a raster of a digital terrain model and that sees **how many cells of a digital height model are traversed** ?

I'm also open to R stat approaches.